# SharePoint 2013 - how to upload static HTML page which is referenced by Iframe

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, html

I have a static XHTML strict document that I created from scratch.  I would like to upload this to my SharePoint 2013 environment, and then embed this page onto one of my SharePoint publishing pages as an iframe.  What steps must I take to make this entire process successful?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some built-in webparts for showing html pages. you could use the page viewer webpart or the content editor webpart.
For example upload your document to site assets of the site you want to show it.
On the page put the content editor webpart and in the webpart settings refer to your uploaded document.